# SOLR ComplexPhrase Range query issues

Tags: solr, lucene

I am trying to query range of numbers within a string. For instance, my query looks like:

```
{!complexphrase inOrder=true}address:"MAIL BOX NUM [10800 TO 10900]"
```

While the results include everything expected, it also includes MAIL BOX NUM 1083, 1084 etc.

These are not within the range defined but it looks like it's doing a "like" search instead of looking for a match within the range. Is there any way to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

It's doing a match within the range - remember that these are not being processed as numbers, but as text. If you sort text, 1083 sorts *after* 10800, but *before* 10900:

```
1080
10800
10801
...
1081
108100
...
1084
...
109000
```

If you want to do something like this, use a regular expression filter to extract the number to its own field (and set the field as an integer), then match against that field for the range.

Comment: Thanks so much for sharing. The issue is that the field cannot be set to integer because it is an alphanumeric field. Any other alternatives here?

Comment: I'm not talking about the field itself, but extracting just the number to a second field (use copyField and then a regular expression char filter to remove everything in front of the number). That will allow you to do what you want.